# In a tungsten filament bulb can be approximated as $P=a(R-b)^4$. Where does the parameter $b$ come from?

Tags: temperature, electric-current, electrical-resistance, power

I did an experiment measuring the voltage drop across and current passing through a tungsten bulb at increasing input voltage. I then calculated the resistance and power from this data, which when plotted on a graph follow the curve $P=a(R-b)^4$ where $b = -5.5$. The resistance of the bulb without current is about $10\Omega$.

I understand the fourth power and relation to the Stefan Boltzmann law, but do not understand what the extra parameter $b$ represents.

Comment: check out this webpage which shows change in resistance vs temperature. http://physics.usask.ca/~bzulkosk/Lab_Manuals/EP354/ep354_thermal-radiation-lab_Tungsten-Temp-Resistivity.pdf

Comment: Can you show a picture of the plot?

Comment: Does this mean that $P=a(R+5.5)$?